# Input Fields in Firefox on a Mac

Tags: macos, firefox

I have an issue that was reported to me just now before we go live tomorrow and I am not able to reproduce as I don't develop on macs and our site is all macs.

I don't have a version number or OS number and know that would make it easier. I am stuck with these two and will do further testing over the weekend.

It was reported to me that when a student tries to login on the site as a student the text appears to big in the input field. Could someone please check it out and send me a screen cap and maybe a firebug screen cap.

sokikom.com -> [Play] (a modal will pop up and you can see what I can't if you type anything into the username box.)

This is not visible in any browser on Windows 7.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks 
Jacob

Comment: Could someone please see if the magnify the browser if they have the problem of only half of the text showing in the username field.

Comment: I guess they were able to produce this on 20 MacBook. I am trying to get the version. Is there some kind high visibility setting on a mac I could try? I have access to a macbook right now and am unable to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox 3.6: Works fine

Safari 5: Works fine

OmniWeb 5.9: Works fine

The text is big, but not too big for the fields.

http://mac.jerrykindall.com:81/sokikom.png

Comment: Thank you very much for the screen cap. The text is supposed to be 24px.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it displays for me in Chrome/Safari/Firefox on 10.6.4. Nothing looks gamebreaking here, unless you don't mean for the "USERNAME" to be that big of a font, but that easy to correct as the font size is 24px for that element.

[image: DISPLAY]

Comment: It is supposed to be 24px. What was reported was that they only able to see half the text. Thank you very much.